# expected a ';' in custom struct

Tags: c, cs50

1. I'm getting this error when I try to use my custom struct in VScode, not quite sure what's going wrong or what it means.
2. error message (expected a ';')

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cs50.h> 
    #include <string.h> 

    typedef struct 
    {
        string itemName;
        string ingredients; 
    }
    database; 
    #define MAX 5; 
    database Mcdonalds[MAX];
    Mcdonalds[0].itemName = "Baked Apple Pie"; 
    (error is displayed about line above)
   ```

Comment: regarding: `Mcdonalds[0].itemName = "Baked Apple Pie";`  cannot assign a string value, except when the receiving array is first defined.  Any actual assignment requires the use of a 'string.h' function, like `strcpy()`  suggest: `strcpy( Mcdonalds[0].itemName, "Baked Apple Pie");`

Comment: regarding: `string itemName;
     string ingredients;`   this only declares two pointers. it does not say what memory that those pointers are pointing at.  The result is Undefined Behavior.  Suggest using: `char itemName[20];
     char ingredients[20];` of course, be sure that what is assigned to those two arrays is 19 characters (or less) to allow room for the terminating NUL byte

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in your macro definition:

```
#define MAX 5;
```

Which causes this:

```
database Mcdonalds[MAX];
```

To become this:

```
database Mcdonalds[5;];
```

Remove the `;` from the macro definition.